# Mongoose save method doesn't update my document

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My model doesn't seem to get updated when I change the values. I have used the `markModified` method, but it doesn't seem to work. After turning on the debug mode (`mongoose.set('debug', true)`). I started analyzing the query. I noticed that the order of how you specify the `_id` is crucial. The user schema has an embedded _id (where I am storing the ObjectID and a custom value I need for my application).

This is the query that Mongoose is generating and it is not working:

```
db.getCollection('user')
  .update(
    { _id: { special_id: 0, user_id: ObjectId("59e8a02ba9986866bad4aa50") }},
    { '$set': { password: 'test' }}
  );
```

I changed the order of the _id and then it works:

```
db.getCollection('user')
  .update(
    { _id: { user_id: ObjectId('59e8a02ba9986866bad4aa50'), special_id: 0 }},
    { '$set': { password: 'test' }}
  );
```

The Mongoose schema looks like this (only showing the _id):

```
const User = new Schema({
  _id: {
    user_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
    },
    xms_id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },      
  },
});
```

And here is the Mongoose query I am using:

```
User.findOne({ reset_password_token: req.params.token })
  .then((user) => {
    if (!doc) {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.markModified('password');

    user.save((err, updatedUser, numAffected) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      console.log('updateduser', updatedUser); // Record with new password
      console.log('numaffacted', numAffected); // 0 records are affected
    });
  })
  .catch(err => next(err));
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? I can't seem to change the order when I want to use `User.save()`.

Comment: Using a compound `_id` is fairly unusual, and it's not well supported by Mongoose. As you've seen, field order matters in this case and you'd probably be better off not using a compound `_id`.

Comment: Sadly I must use an compound `_id` in my use case. I guess I have to find another way for changing the data. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: where is special_id in your model? if your id-model has no special_id (undefined), but you provide special_id:0, its not the same and nothing will match. why don't you use User.update() to update your model? also, you shouldn't use a subdocument as id, if you can, try putting the 2 fields directly into the User model, mark them both as unique and apply an compound index (new Schema(...).index({ field1:1, field2:1 ...}) to them.